# Parse a date in VimScript

Tags: vim, viml

Given a date string of the form "2012-09-31", I'd like a vimscript function to parse it so I can calculate relative dates. Pure vimscript or python solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

For normal mode manipulation of dates there is the superb [SpeedDating](https://github.com/tpope/vim-speeddating) plugin from Tim Pope. In principle it should be possible to extract some of the internal functions of this plugin to use in other scripts, but I don't know how easy that is in practice.

Comment: yep. I looked at it. It's very powerful, but not obvious how I would extract this little piece of functionality :)

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, here's my current solution. Better suggestions or improvements are welcome.

```
function! AdjustDate(date, offset)
python << EOF
import vim
import datetime

result = datetime.datetime.strptime(vim.eval("a:date"), "%Y-%m-%d") + \
        datetime.timedelta(days=int(vim.eval("a:offset")))
vim.command("let l:result = '" + result.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") + "'")
EOF
return result
endfunction
```